# Calculate columnwise total for dynamic columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, calculated-columns, dynamic-columns

I have the following output which is generated from stored procedure which is the following

```
   SET @sql = '

   SELECT  * FROM (SELECT [NAMES],logdate,[worked time] 
   from tmp_phys_table GROUP BY NAMES,LOGDATE,[WORKED TIME]) AS [SubTable] 
   PIVOT
   (
    MAX([worked time])
             FOR [logdate] IN ([' + @docDates + '])
       ) AS [Pivot] ;';
```

The above query gives the following output

[image: output datat]

Now I want to do a columnwise total and include a new column called total time at the end of the columns which are dynamic columns eg. there may be 3 columns or 30 columns.

Comment: I am trying to put the output in a physical table which is not happening..but that can be another question.Need help with the above

Comment: This column `Total Time` already exists but you want to get It on select clause? Or you need to add new column? If It is new column, how It should calculat total time (of which column total time)?

Comment: @Stanislovas Kalašnikovas Yes,the column already exists,I want that column in select statement

Comment: In which table this column exists?

Comment: tmp_phys_table which is there in the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be something like that:

```
   SET @sql = '

   SELECT *
   FROM (SELECT [NAMES], logdate, [worked time], [Total Time] 
         FROM tmp_phys_table 
         GROUP BY NAMES,LOGDATE,[WORKED TIME], [Total Time]
         ) AS [SubTable] 
   PIVOT
   (
    MAX([worked time])
             FOR [logdate] IN ([' + @docDates + '])
       ) AS [Pivot] ;';
```

Comment: Stanislovas Kalašnikovas I executed the query,it gave the following error Incorrect syntax near ']'.

Comment: Stanislovas Kalašnikovas : any way of getting this output into a physical table

Comment: Try now. Updated answer.